# C# Use Windows Message Queue

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, remote-control

i have to realize a project ..the idea is very simple..

Usually we have to work with different pc with different os for variuous reasons.
This is not a problem for what regards monitor, but is a problem for what regards mouse and keyboard...
Is easy make confusion with 10 mouse and 10 keyboard on the desk ...wich keyboard control a particular monitor?

The controlled pc have a server program .
The principal pc will control them with a client program after autentication with password.

So the principal pc is a sort of controller, anything else... it receive the events and send the event to the chosen pc...

My question is:

For what regards mouse is very easy to simulate it,But how can i simulate keyboard event?
have i to use the windows message queue...it's correct?
Have you got some example? i dont know exactly what have i to search on the web...:(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most of the peripherals, use windows messaging for communication.

You can google for:

1. Windows messaging sample for keyboard emulation
2. "Windows messaging in WinCE", this will give you some good examples.